# Passing objects across multiple nested classes

Tags: php

I'm running into a problem when passing an object across different classes and trying to have only one instance of it instead of multiple clones.

TLDR version:

If I have objects `A->B->C`, where `C` gets passed `A` by way of `B` as a parameter on creation, will `C->A->B` access the original `B` that had created it, or a copy of that `B`? How many copies of `B` are there in the system memory now?

Slightly more detailed version:

Let's say I have a (perhaps overly convoluted) nested class structure for handling a server-based request. The first step is to instantiate an object of class `Session`, and then within it, create an object `$handler` of class `Handler`. However, as `$handler` will need to have access to the internal attributes of `$session` (and multiple other objects created within it, like `$user` or `$database`, whose purposes ought to be self-explanatory), I then pass it on as a parameter:

```
class Session {
 public $handler;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->handler = new Handler( $this );

  //DO STUFF HERE
 }
}
```

The `Handler` class inherits the session like this:

```
class Handler {
 private $session;

 public function __construct( Session $inherited_session ) {
  $this->session = $inherited_session;
 }
}
```

Side note: `$session` is set to `private` to avoid even the slightest chance of infinite loops down the line, of the `$this->session->handler->session->handler` variety.

Now, according to my understanding and all the research I've done, PHP passes objects by reference, so the `$this->session` object within this `Handler` ought to be accessing the same object in the system memory as the original session? Not a copy of itself?

Yet here's my problem. Suppose now I create a third-level nested object within the `Handler` class, of class `Dashboard`, and want to pass the original `$session` to it (not, mind it, just the `Handler` object itself). Off we go, so we put this somewhere within the `Handler` class:

```
  $dashboard = new Dashboard( $this->session );
```

The `Dashboard` constructor inherits the session in exactly the same way as `Handler` did:

```
class Dashboard {
 private $session;

 public function __construct( Session $inherited_session ) {
  $this->session = $inherited_session;
 }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem able to access the instance of `Handler` that had called it, and by now it appears that we have multiple copies of `$session` and `$handler` floating about - and I'd very much like to understand why, because it contradicts everything I understand about references.

Here's an example of this pathological behaviour - say we have a variable in `Handler`:

```
  public $temp_var;
```

that the constructor of `Handler` assigns a value:

```
  $this->temp_var = '123';
```

and then we try accessing it from within the `Dashboard` class as `$this->session->handler->temp_var`. That returns `NULL`. Why? Did `$dashboard` inherit a copy of `$session` on initialisation that doesn't have an initialised `->handler` to call on? How can I make it so there is only one (unique) object of each class, and updating the internal (public) variables of `$handler` would get correctly passed on to `$dashboard->session->handler`? Or am I just making some obvious / idiotic mistake somewhere and completely not seeing it?

Note #1: any variable set in `$session` as `$this->var` is correctly accessible from `$dashboard->session->var`, so double-level nesting works as expected; it's triple-level one that doesn't.

Note #2: I've already thought of simply passing `$handler` as a parameter to all of its nested objects *along with* `$session` (and if no solution exists, this is what I'll have to do), but it doesn't solve the original problem of `$this->session->handler` being somehow and inexplicably different from the original `$handler` within its nested objects.

Oh, and my thanks to anyone who managed to read through all this!

Comment: TL;DR… But… there are only as many objects as you create. Every `new` creates a new object, a `clone` copies an object. Unless you `clone` your objects, you will always get a reference to the one and only instance of it.

Comment: The error lies somewhere in your code, objects aren't cloned or copied without you explicitly telling PHP to do so.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought as well, but I've literally just spent 4 hours this morning at work looking for an error in the code, and found absolutely nothing, so asking this question here is just an act of desperation really

Comment: If you spent so much time trying to debug your own code, that's a clear sign you need to invest into unit testing and that your code does more harm to its developer than good (you shouldn't be spending hours and hours to find where object isn't available). This seems like you're creating your own framework. Have you considered using the ones that are available?

Comment: From the code shown your Session and Dashboard classes don't seem to keep a reference to Handler, or did I miss something? If this is the case, some variation of `return $this->handler || new Handler()` (pseudocode I know) could be ruining your day.

Comment: ppajer: good point, though unfortunately that's just me failing to mention it here - Session does have a reference to Handler, I've adjusted the original text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you're dealing with `composition` not with `inheritance` here.

So, you have a `Session` which is passed to a `Handler`, the `Handler` and `Dashboard` both "know" the session through composition (keeping a reference on the private variable).

I don't understand why do you need this sort of circular reference, but if you want to access the `Handler` from `Dashboard`, why not passing the `Handler` to it?

Besides that, it looks like you are storing the handler in a local scoped variable (I've been away from PHP the last two years, but...)

```
class Session {

  public function __construct() {
    // isnt $this->handler = new Handler( $this ) ??
    $handler = new Handler( $this );
  }
}
```

From a conceptual point of view, there's not "nesting", only references, so I dont think that the "three levels" does anything to do with that.

Hope it helps!

[Here's an example](https://repl.it/EL8B/2) I've modified the Session and privacy just to verify that the $session is still the same

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned in another comment above, that's just me not copying it here properly, $handler is actually a public variable in the class Session and it's, of course, $this->handler = new Handler( $this ); 

Should've noticed that I copied it incorrectly, apologies.

Comment: So, as you can see in the link, it works, maybe you're doing something else that brokes your references

Comment: I think your problem is that you're trying to access to `$this->session->handler->temp_var` immediatly, so you've to debug when its available to you... but again, you've a lot of recursion, it seems like you need to spend more time designing your objects